# Why ios device cannot show third-party font correctly?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

### Swift/Xcode 6/iOS 8.3

I've followed the tutorial, copied the .ttf file to the project and added the `fonts provided by application` in `info.plist`. After this, the font looks just OK in the interface builder, but it was reverted to Helvetica Neue on the simulator. And I'm using the `Plain` text, not the `Attributed` one.

Is there any other way to set the imported font right in the IB instead of ctrl+drag an IBOutlet and set its font programmatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work when you set it programmatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check that u add target for u font.
Go to  `settings->build phases->copy bundle resources`. There must be all fonts, that u add for app.

or click to ur font in `Navigator` and check `target member` in `Utilities`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you K.K. I owe you a beer.